# Как убрать задержку появления tooltip?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, tooltip

Есть у меня один `QComboBox`, на котором висит `tooltip`. Как можно ускорить появления этой подсказки? Qt 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать наследоваться от `QComboBox` и перегрузить метод `mouseMoveEvent` в котором вызвать статический метод [QToolTip::showText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtooltip.html#showText):

```
#include <QToolTip>
#include <QMouseEvent>

MyCombo::MyCombo(QWidget *parent):
    QComboBox(parent)
{
    // Надо установить в true, чтобы вызывался метод mouseMoveEvent
    setMouseTracking(true);
}

void MyCombo::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *evt)
{
    QComboBox::mouseMoveEvent(evt);
    // Qt 6.0+
    QToolTip::showText(evt->globalPosition().toPoint(), "Tool Tip");
    // Qt 6.0-
    QToolTip::showText(evt->globalPos(), "Tool Tip");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Забыл написать, что у меня Qt 5.6. Для него подойдет:
QToolTip::showText(evt->globalPos(), "Tool Tip");

Comment: @LetynnC отлично, добавлю ваше уточнение в ответ с вашего позволения